# Java AssertionError but I get correct answer

Tags: java, assert

I was testing some of my methods for my class and I got the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: com.company.ArrayList<[ 11 12 ]> but was: com.company.ArrayList<[ 11 12 ]>
```

I fail to see the difference. Basically what I have is this test:

```
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
    List ot = new ArrayList();
    ot.add(11);
    ot.add(12);
    prg = new ProgState(ot);

}
```

prg was declared before in the class, as private.

```
@Test
public void testGetOut() throws Exception {
    List wtf = new ArrayList();
    wtf.add(11);
    wtf.add(12);
    assertEquals(wtf, prg.getOut());
}
```

ArrayList is my own ADT, List is interface, ProgState is just:

```
public class ProgState {
private List out;

public ProgState(List ot) {
    out = ot;
}

public List getOut() {
    return out;
}
```

It's just returning my list. Why won't it accept ot  = [11, 12] being the same as wtf = [11, 12]? I have no idea at all.

Comment: _"ArrayList is my own ADT"_ Then show its equals implementation.

Comment: Seems like you implemented your own `com.company.ArrayList`. Can you share its implementation? Specifically - did you overwrite the `equals(Object)` method?

Comment: Yea I did. I ended up not overriding the equals but changing the whole perspective. I made another Array, added the same ints I added in the first one and just used the method .get(0) on both of of them twice and compared the results, changing a flag if I got a wrong answer. I applied the assert on the flag. Thank you for your answer and sorry for not replying back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ArrayList is my own ADT

I will venture to guess that you haven't overridden the `equals` method in your ADT.
By the default implementation it inherits from `Object`, all distinct instances (created by `new`) are NOT equal.

You need to override this method and implement comparing the elements: the sizes must match and the elements must be equal pairwise: both null or both non-null and equals by their `equals` methods.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the `.equals()` function for `Object` enforces equality through `==`.  Because your two lists don't represent the same `Object`, this check fails during your `assertEquals()` call.